# How can I properly escape this regex in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, grep, escaping, quoting

I'm trying to run grep with the following regex:

```
(?<!key:)(?<!orKey:)(?<!isEqualToString:)\@\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\"
```

First try:

```
$ grep -r -n  -H -E (?<!key:)(?<!orKey:)(?<!isEqualToString:)\@\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\" ./
    -bash: !key: event not found
```

Ok, so I need to escape the "!"s...

```
$ grep -r -n  -H -E (?<\!key:)(?<\!orKey:)(?<\!isEqualToString:)\@\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\" ./
    -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Ok, so I need to escape the "("s...

```
$ grep -r -n  -H -E \(?<\!key:\)\(?<\!orKey:\)\(?<\!isEqualToString:\)\@\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\" ./
    -bash: !key:)(?: No such file or directory
```

Ok, so I need to quote the string?

```
$ grep -r -n  -H -E '\(?<\!key:\)\(?<\!orKey:\)\(?<\!isEqualToString:\)\@\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\"' ./
```

Returns no results... but I tried a simpler regex which doesn't have the negative-look-behind assertions, and it ran fine... I also used TextWrangler with this regex and it does work, so I can only assume I'm doing something wrong on the command line here.

**EDIT:**

If I use the `-p` option:

```
$ grep -r -n  -H -E -P '\(?<\!key:\)\(?<\!orKey:\)\(?<\!isEqualToString:\)\@\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\"' ./
grep: conflicting matchers specified
```

An example of file contents which should match:

```
NSString * foo = @"bar";
```

An example of file contents which should NOT match:

```
return [someDictonary objectForKey:@"foo"];
```

Comment: In general, quoting with '...' is far preferable to escaping. Escaping will mutilate your regex, make it less intuitive, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the core of it you need to quote the entire string with `''`. (If you enclose with `""` the `!` will give you grief). Then you only need to escape internal `'` within your regex (if any).

Also you want `-P` (perl) instead of `-E` (egrep) regex.

```
grep -r -n -H -P '(?<!key:)(?<!orKey:)(?<!isEqualToString:)\@\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\"' ./
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. That works! So, If I enclose the regex in single-ticks I don't have to escape the !s?

Comment: Yep. Otherwise within a `"` or if not quoted at all, `!` has a special meaning in bash.

Answer (score 4):

try using the **-P** option which will interpret the regex as a perl regex.  Also if you provide some example input and output it would help in getting an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my question. Like I said, the regex itself works great through TextWrangler (which uses grep internally) - so I'm pretty positive this is a bash quoting problem.

Comment: @Steve, it's quite possible that TextWranger uses `grep -P` internally. (checking manual now...)

Comment: I couldn't accept two answers, so best I can do is +1. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ennuikiller You got a +1 from me too for coming first to the rescue!! :)

Answer (score 3):

`'` quoting works perfectly as long as there are no `'` in your expression. And you don't have any, so that should be fine.

If you are really paranoid about quoting, put the expression in a file and use `grep -f FILENAME` instead, so that it reads the regex from the file.

But the real issue might be that you need to specify `grep -P` to explicitly ask for the Perl regular expression support.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine, just avoid using conflicting options.  -

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat filename
NSString * foo = @"bar";
return [someDictonary objectForKey:@"foo"];

[jaypal:~/Temp] grep -P '(?<!key:)(?<!orKey:)(?<!isEqualToString:)\@\"[A-Za-z0-9]*\"' filename
NSString * foo = @"bar";
```